# iOS how to hide Number pad when click in background / and Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

Trying to hide the Number pad pressure in background.
The problem is that Xcode 4 did not find how can I attach event in the background.

Here is my code.

SecondViewController.h

```
  - (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender;
```

SecondViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Xcode]

Answer (score 1):

Change you main view from a UIView to a UIControl then you will be able to use touch down events for the background.

Answer (score 0):

use touchesBegan:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```